# Terminology: what is the correct term to refer to a *particular* browser, OS and device combination?

Tags: browsers, testing, cross-browser, definition

We all do "browser testing" on a variety of web browsers, operating systems and devices. But what is the correct term to refer to a **particular** browser, OS and device combination?

Or, to put it another way - what is the type of which the following are tokens?:

- Google Chrome (latest version) on Mac OS X 10.8.5, MacBook Pro 13"
- Safari 6 on iOS 7, iPhone 4S

Reading through various developer blogs and websites of online browser testing services, it seems that most copywriters simply find ways to avoid using a term for this. But, in many cases, this strikes me as awkward and verbose.

The best term I've come up with so far is *browser environment*, but I'd love to hear if anyone either (a) knows the standard term for this or (b) can think of something better than my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I've always referred to it as "browser and platform".  It isn't a single term, but it is short enough.

The header that that comes in is the "User-Agent" header.  "User agent" is another general term for this combination.   The only problem with 'user agent" is that the same browser on the same operating system can have multiple user agent strings based on smaller differences such as the user's language, and plugins that are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure its the term your looking for, but its means what you explain here.

"Cross Browser Testing" - The [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/)  is one of the tool from this category it provides a correct results on different OS and browser versions. Its uses remote desktop access method and you can even check mobile devices too.